# Is there any specific payload we need to feed to Batch execute?

Tags: mule

I have Community Edition Mule so I don't have access to Batch process but I do have a doubt.

Batch Execute is a message processor that leads the flow to Batch Process.
Do we need to put any specific payload in Batch execute for surccessfull Batch Processing? For eg: Java object payload or a payload passed through a splitter which is easy for Batch process to manage?

Comment: You neednot required to put any specific payload in it. It is a flowRef for batch scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not using a a batch input phase then yes batch:execute must be fed an instance of one of the following types: interface java.lang.Iterable, interface java.util.Iterator, interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence, interface java.util.Collection.

Answer (score -1):

Batch execute act similar to `flowRef` message processor ( used to call another flow). If you have batch scope flow, you can call the batchScope flow via `Batch Execute` from other flows.

Comment: yeah i know that.. this is the functionality of Batch execute but I need to know that we need to give any specific payload to 'batch Execute' or will it work for any payload fed to it?